# Updating Page won't work

Tags: php, mysql

thanks to you all for this great web-site, it's my second time asking a question, I hope it's not too much ^^
I'm working on my project, and I've got kind of a weird issue with my update page, 
it's basically displaying all data from a table in mysql, and when I checkbox the two rows to update them with new informations, it copies all new informations from the "(last row only)" and copy it all over the other rows, and the result is , all row become identical !!!! am I doing something wrong ? please help me guys this is my code..

I ALSO when I try to update any other row it wont update, but only update the last row...

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['username']) ){
 include('../CIEcon.php');


echo "<form action= 'adminCleaning.php'  method = 'post'>" ; 

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        if( isset($_POST['id']) ){
                if( empty($_POST['id']) || $_POST['id'] == 0 ){
                    echo"<h4>  please choose something to delete   </h4>";
                  }else{

            echo $implid = implode("' , '", $_POST['id']);

            $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Cleaning  SET  JobName= '$_POST[jobname]',Description= '$_POST[description]',NoStudent='$_POST[nostudent]',DueDate='$_POST[duedate]' WHERE Id IN('" . $implid . "')";
            $resultUpdate = mysqli_query($dbCIE,$sqlUpdate )or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));


        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbCIE) > 0) {
            echo "You have successfully updated your data.<br><br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "The data you submitted matched the current data so nothing was changed.<br><br>";
        }


        } // end of else..


        } // end of  if isset($_POST['id']) ... 
} // end of   if isset($_POST['update']) ... 


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Cleaning  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));

                  /// NOW DISPLAY ALL INFO FROM CHOSEN DATABASE...
                            echo "

                            <table cellpadding ='4' border='1' width='80%' align='center'>
                            <tr>

                            <th class='tt' >Check </th>
                            <th class='tt'> Job's Name</th>
                            <th class='tt' >Description</th>
                            <th class='tt' > No Students needed</th>
                            <th class='tt' >Due Date</th>
                            </tr>";

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo "<br>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='id[]'  value='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>";  // array[] cause to edit more than one record... 
                            echo "<td><input type='text' name='jobname' value='" . $row['JobName']  . "'> </td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' name='description' value='" . $row['Description']  . "'> </td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' name='nostudent' value='" . $row['NoStudent']  . "'> </td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' name='duedate' value='" . $row['DueDate']  . "'> </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                   /// END THE SEARCH HERE...........

                            echo " <br>
                                <div align='center'>
                                <input type='reset' value='clear' /> 

                                <input type='submit' name='update' value='update' />

                                </div> ";

                          mysqli_close($dbCIE);

echo "</form>";
}
else{echo "must logout to see this page..!!";}

?>

<html>

<head><title> ..Cleanding.... </title></head>

<style type="text/css">

body{
    margin-top: 70px;    /*space above the table....*/
    background-color: #23438e; 
}
table{
    background-color: white; 
}


.tt{
    background: #f26822;
    color: white ;
}
</style>


<body>

<!-- <a href= "../AdminIndex.php" > <button> Main Page </button></a>     -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all your inputs have the same name, and you are using an **IN** to update, rather than an **=**

Change your input tags to follow this pattern:

```
<input type='text' name='jobname[".$row['Id']."]' value='" . $row['JobName']  . "'>
```

and the SQL to use this pattern:

```
JobName= '$_POST[jobname][$id]' ... WHERE Id = $id
```

If more than one id is sent at a time, you'll need a loop to loop through all the inputs and run the query.

Each row of the HTML table should be sent to the server with a unique id, and each update should be sent to the database with the appropriate data and id.

Comment: you are missing the closing `]` in `name='jobname[".$row['Id']."'`. should be `name='jobname[".$row['Id']."]'`